# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code.I'm using an API call in useEffect just like following:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getQuotationById = async () => {
        const resp = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}quotation-details/${id}`);
        setData(resp.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getData().catch((e) => {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(e);
        });
    }, []);

return <div>
 {data.quantities.split('/').map((quantity, index) => (<span>quantity</span>)
</div>
```

The interesting thing is that an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') in react` always comes out.

But there is no error if I use the optional chain in the `return` sytanx like:

```
return <div>
 {data.quantities?.split('/').map((quantity, index) => (<span>quantity</span>)
</div>
```

Why this happens?

Comment: By the time it first renders it doesn't have the data yet ....

Comment: try conditional rendering, while it has not loaded the data yet, render something else, like a spinner or a progress bar, after it has loaded the data, render the data. i am assuming you are using `data` of this component, maybe i am wrong, why use `props.data`?

Comment: Where does `props` come from and what does it have to do with your component's state?

Comment: It is a typo.It should be data rather props.data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your code, it could be two reasons.

1. In the first time the code executes, there could be no data assigned to the data property.
2. If this is the same component, you are using the data from props. If you are not passing the props, it will be undefined. Or you want to use the data in the same component remove `props.data` and just use `data`.